# Every projection of the square of the middle thirds Cantor set contains an interval

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, fractals, geometric-measure-theory

> Let $C_\lambda$ the cantor set which is defined by the IFS $\{\lambda x,\lambda x+(1-\lambda)\}$ and also let $E=C_\lambda\times C_\lambda$.Suppose $\lambda =\frac 1 3$, we get the standard middle-thirds cantor sets. Denote the orthogonal projection of the set from the plane to the line which makes $\theta$ degrees. 
>   show that $P_\theta E$ contains an interval for a.e $\theta$.

Here I don't know from where to start. I know that the Lebesgue measure of the set is non-negative but that's not really useful here. I'll be glad for any hint.

Comment: It does not contain an interval when $\theta=0$ or $\theta=\pi/2$.

Comment: Is not this just a special case of your [earlier question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1072080/147263)?

Comment: @Behaviour How can you tell, if the question is misstated? Here is a statement that definitely *is* true: If we project the point $(x_0,y_0)$ along a line of slope one, we hit the $x$-axis at the point $x_0-y_0$. Now, it's well known that $C-C=[-1,1]$; this can be proven using the triadic expansion representation of $C$. As a result, the projection along this direction certainly contains an interval.

Comment: @Behaviour definitely no, There we require a subset and here it's for a.e $\theta$ and specific $\lambda$ value.

Comment: This is false. The dimension of the set E is 1 and there exists two \theta for which the projection has measure zero. Hence by Besicovitch's theorem projection of E will have measure zero for \theta ae. (If projection had an interval then it's measure can't be zero)